# Ffmpeg alpha from udp input

Tags: video, ffmpeg, udp, alpha, avi

I'm trying to stream a video that is composed from a base video and an overlay video with an alpha channel.

I receive both of the incoming input streams as udp inputs so I can change them at runtime.

The problem is that when I use avi as the format for the overlay stream i get this error:

> udp://127.0.0.1:${port2}: Invalid data found when processing input

and when I use mpegts as the format for the overlay stream I get this error:

> Stream specifier ':v' in filtergraph description [0:v][1:v]overlay=format=rgb matches no streams

The main ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i udp://127.0.0.1:${port1} -vcodec qtrle -i udp://127.0.0.1:${port2} -s 854x480 -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=format=rgb -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -f flv ${output}
```

The base stream:

```
ffmpeg -re -i ${hls_source} -c:v libx264 -vf scale=854:480 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:${port1}
```

The overlay stream with alpha channel:

```
ffmpeg -re -i z.mov -vcodec qtrle -f avi udp://127.0.0.1:${port2}
```

It's worth noting that when I switch one of the udp inputs with a recorded file, It does work.

Comment: Have you tried  `-f avi -i udp://127.0.0.1:${port2}`?

Comment: I get the same error "Invalid data found when processing input"

Comment: Is there any other format with an alpha channel that might work?

Comment: VP8/9 with the libvpx decoders, any image format like PNG sent/received using `-f image2pipe`

Comment: This doesn't work as well both vp8 and vp9,
The closest I got was with qtrle but I get the error `Unsupported colorspace: 0 bits/sample?
`